# Knowing whether or not an Insert Ignore (MySQL) actually inserted in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Right now I am using Insert Ignore to insert a bunch of tuples into my DB. However, I want to know whether or not the tuple was actually inserted or not and based on that do some action. Code is in PHP:

```
if(!($stmt4 = $mysqliprivate3->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO ".$table." VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))){
                                echo "Prepare Failed3: (" . $mysqliprivate3->errno . ") " . $mysqliprivate3->error;
                            }
                            else{
                                $stmt4->bind_param("ssisssssssssssss", $id, $dt, $score, $question1, $question2, $question3,$question4,$question5,$question6,$question7,$question8,$question9a,$question9b,$question9c,$question9d,$question9e);
                                $stmt4->execute();
                                $stmt4->close();
                            }
                            //if(inserted){
                                Do something
                            }
```

I have tried using 
 `echo $mysqliprivate3->affected_rows;`
but it seems to give me a 1 even if it isn't inserting anything. What else could I do?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe a collision will result in a warning, but issuing and processing a `SHOW WARNINGS` statement would be a pain.  (I suspect there's a much better way, but not sure what API you're using, nor am I very familiar with how MySQL handles this.)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if ($stmt4->affected_rows)
{
    // ...
}
```